# PHP - Can I set a static ID/Password for a page using CodeIgniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm doing my website with PHP using CodeIgniter framework.
I have some pages that I want to hide from users, and I just want to do very simple authentication. For example, I just hardcode an ID and a password in my header script, and requires users to enter ID and password to show the contents. Is it possible to do that with CodeIgniter ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the PHP Basic authentification: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

```
<?php

$user = 'foo';
$pwd = 'bar';

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    askForPwd();
}
else
{
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] !== $user && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] !== $pwd)
    {
        askForPwd();
    }

    // continue execution
}

function askForPwd()
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as basic as it gets. User wants to go to hidden page 1, if they have no session they are redirected to the login page (just needs a post to itself and an id and password field and a place to `echo $msg`). Once logged in they will be redirected back to the hidden page and can view contents.

This can be cleaned up a bit, but it is the general idea.

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    private $id = '123';
    private $password = 'abc';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function login_page() {
        $data = array();
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            if ($id == $this->id && $password == $this->password) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('auth', TRUE);
                if ($this->session->has_userdata('redirect_to')) {
                    redirect($this->session->redirect_to);
                    exit;
                }
                // no redirect specified, display message
                $data['msg'] = 'Logged in.';
            } else {
                $data['msg'] = 'Wrong credentials.';
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }

    public function hidden_content_1() {
       if (!$this->session->has_userdata('auth')) {
           $this->session->set_userdata('redirect_to', uri_string());
           redirect('auth/login_page');
       }
       echo 'If you are seeing this you are logged in!';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be a role type related with your user and you can set a role for public users. After that You can check that in your controller Using Codeigniter session. If you share your controller and model. We can help you..